# SD CARD Inserted OR Device mount as DIsk

Tags: android, android-sdcard

In my application, I am recording voice and then play it afterwards, but there seems some problem when my device have no SD card or my device connected to my computer(mount as disk drive only). my application got closed whenever i am trying to record something in these two cases.

**1st case** (i.e. When NO SD card) :-

```
Boolean isSDPresent = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);
```

**Case 1** was handled using this. But how can do I handle the **2nd case** (i.e.) **When my device is mounted as disk**.

I have gone through various links but didn't get what I wanted.
thanks in advance.

Comment: I wonder, why the case2 is not covered by the same test?

Comment: @Henry- actually i just want two different toasts/messages on these cases.and what code i used for 1st case that doesn't differentiate between these two cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey i just got the answer: we can use these Constants for 2nd case and For first case as well.
Link for solutions.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html
thanks